# Buttons to create promotions and experiments are disabled in Targeting Tab of web8.1.1 CME

Tags: web8, experience-optimization

On click of Targeting Tab in CME it shows Promotion and Experiments tabs view but the buttons for creating new promotions and new Experiments are disabled. Also the source drop down is empty. I am logged in with Admin user and it has access rights to manage promotions and experiments in the business process Types - Target type security tab. Is there any thing I am missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root cause of issue was "SmartTargetManagementCapability" was not registered properly. After I manually register the same using discovery registeration tool (discovery-registeration.jar) it works perfectly fine and now I am able to see enabled buttons to create promotions, Experiments etc.